# How does the Java compiler handle StringBuilder(a + b + c + d)?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am dealing with an application that contains lots of legacy code.
What I see very often is string concatenation using "+" within a StringBuilder argument.
Example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("This "
        + "looks "
        + "rather "
        + "weird "
        + "to "
        + "me.")
```

From what I've learned the compiler replaces a string concatenation that uses the + operator with StringBuilder().append().
I am afraid now the compiler will create a temporary StringBuilder to perform the concatenation then convert toString() and insert the result into the existing StringBuilder.

My Question is: Is the compiler able to optimize the nested StringBuilder away? And if not should I rewrite the code to save a few CPU cycles? It is obviously working but it hurts my eyes whenever I look at it.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Where do you saw `compiler replaces a string concatenation that uses the + operator with StringBuilder().append()` ? If that was true, we wouldn't care to use StringBuilder or string concatenation

Comment: @azro: That logic doesn't follow at all. `StringBuilder` allows you to *dynamically* append (e.g. in a loop). I believe `+` *does* use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @azro Yes, using concatenation through `+` **will** be implicitly translated to use `StringBuilder`. Only when concatenating over multiple statements, especially when looping, you should use `StringBuilder` explicitly.

Comment: @azro: It can be seen in the call stack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler optimizes concatenation of String literal constants:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("This "
        + "looks "
        + "rather "
        + "weird "
        + "to "
        + "me.");
```

is exactly equivalent, at runtime, to:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("This looks rather weird to me.");
```

This also applies to any String compile-time constants, not just literals.

The concern you may have read about is when using non-constants:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("This "
        + arg1
        + var2);
```

is equivalent to:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(new StringBuilder("This ")
        .append(arg1)
        .append(var2)
        .toString());
```

and it would give you better performance if you re-wrote that as:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("This ")
        .append(arg1)
        .append(var2);
```

Comment: If the string builder is not used for anything else, replacing it with `"This " + arg1 + var2` is even more efficient. Dealing with a `StringBuilder` only pays off when conditional fragments or loops are involved. By the way, the compile-time constant folding applies to all constants, not only strings, e.g. `"a " + 1 + " b"` get compiled to `"a 1 b"`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @k314159's answer, determining how the compiler transforms any particular block of code is easy if you isolate it, compile it with `javac`, and run the disassembler on it using `javap` to view the generated (annotated) bytecode.

For example, if you isolate the StringBuilder code into a minimal class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("This "
        + "looks "
        + "rather "
        + "weird "
        + "to "
        + "me.");
    }
}
```

You can then compile and disassemble the output like so:

```
javac Test.java && javap -c Test.class
```

The output for which is:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       3: dup
       4: ldc           #3                  // String This looks rather weird to me.
       6: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       9: astore_1
      10: return
}
```

The line of interest to you, in this case, would be here:

```
4: ldc           #3                  // String This looks rather weird to me.
```

As you might've guessed, this instruction pushes a (string) constant onto the stack. The annotation clearly states that the constant in this case is a single string, namely: `"This looks rather weird to me."`

Hopefully that demystifies the internals slightly!